# Trajectory interpolation for ROS-I robot driver

Tags: ros, moveit, kuka, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I have develop a driver for the KUKA LWR 4+ by use of the FRI Library.
The driver designed like the [ros-i driver spec](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Industrial_Robot_Driver_Spec) and so it works also with MoveIt!

If I plan a trajectory with MoveIt I will get a trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory message with the waypoints. But how to interpolate correctly between the points?

I have a internal cycle time of 1ms and need to sample the trajectory down to this constant interval. Do I really need to build up splines based on the waypoints or can I tell MoveIt to sample the trajectory with 1ms?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214847/trajectory-interpolation-for-ros-i-robot-driver./) by [CTieben](https://answers.ros.org/users/23393/ctieben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CTieben](https://answers.ros.org/users/23393/ctieben/) on 2015-08-14**:
There is a [ROS Industrial Trajectory Filter](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_trajectory_filters) for exactly this problem. It a ROS Type Wrapper for the KDL Velocity Profile Spline to sample it down to n-parts or duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Do I really need to build up splines based on the waypoints or can I tell MoveIt to sample the trajectory with 1ms?

If I recall correctly, MoveIt sort-of assumes a lower-level controller that accepts `JointTrajectory` messages exists, and that that lower-level controller will do all the 'heavy lifting' to execute the trajectory. In the case of the PR2 that is the whole real-time capable [pr2_controllers](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers) infrastructure. That is not really usable with other robots though.

You might be able to re-use the controllers in the [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control) package. One of the supported interfaces is a `JointTrajectoryAction` server, which internally runs PID (or custom, more advanced) controllers to take joints through the trajectory points it receives. The `ros_control` nodes are capable of running in real-time as well. Be sure to watch the presentation Adolfo gave on ROSCon14, it provides a much more in-depth picture of what is going on then the documentation currently does.

Note that `ros_control` by default does not expose a ROS-Industrial compatible motion interface, but that can be solved by remapping a few topics.

---

Edit: you might also be interested in the ongoing work in the [kuka_experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental) repository of the ROS-Industrial Github organisation, and the [ros-sig-kuka](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-kuka) mailing list. The `kuka_experimental` repository has an open PR for a `ros_control` based driver using RSI. Perhaps you can use it as an example of how to implement a similar system for FRI.

Contacting either the ROS-Industrial [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) and / or the `ros-sig-kuka` would be a good idea anyway: there are a number of projects currently underway ([CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr](https://github.com/CentroEPiaggio/kuka-lwr) being one of them), and it would be nice to avoid redoing existing work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1